# How to delay loading file_get_contents option until the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following on my page:

```
<?php echo(file_get_contents("http://$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]/X.php?logon=Y&vendorref=".$row_RS_Product['id']."&mode=product"));?>
```

How can I prevent it from loading until the page has loaded, as it slows the page load down very much.
Any help welcome

Comment: You can't prevent it there. php is server-side and will be executed on request. You have to build something with js and ajax then.

Comment: You can load that asynchronously with ajax.